# PostgreSQL query to Rails Console.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The query which i have been trying to formulate is

```
select array_agg(is_online) , config->> 'external_host' from cameras group by config->> 'external_host';
```

this is running fine on PostgreSql query console, but not giving any response on Rails console not even error.
is there any way to formulate that query in some way that it will be applicable for ActiveRecords?

Comment: same as i have pasted here, the same in console, bu the way @Abhi told me results are nill

Answer (score 1):

Try `find_by_sql`.

Eg:-

```
ModelName.find_by_sql("sql_query;")
```

[Reference DOC](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class)

If you are using rails version above **3.1.x** then use a gem `gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'`

Answer (score 1):

Try select query with model

```
Camera.select('cameras.column1 AS t_column1, cameras.column2 AS t_column2, , count(*) AS total').group('t_column1, t_column2')
```